# How to make numpad key binds such as Ctrl + Alt + 1 work in KDE?

Tags: kde, numpad

I am running latest **Kubuntu KDE**, was trying to set up virtual desktop switching key bindings same as I used in Gnome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Number_Of_Desktop</kbd>.

I always used numpad to press the number, but this does not want to work in KDE.
When I press numbers above the qwerty keys they work! But numpad does not.
Can you suggest where I should dig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bug report: Bug 183458 - Numpad (keypad) keys not mapped correctly when setting Global Shortcuts / https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183458

The bug report has a workaround "Comment #17 From Pistos"

Answer (score 0):

yes its worked ^ after installing **`xbindkeys`**, try it on your distribution just configure the ~/.xbindkeysrc file and enjoy it

dont worry this package have a helpfull man page just read this

my .xbindkeys configuration:

```
## begin .xbindkeys

# Switch between desktops

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Switch One Desktop to the Left'"
Control + Shift + Mod2 + h

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Switch One Desktop to the Right'"
Control + Shift + Mod2 + l

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Switch One Desktop Down'"
Control + Shift + Mod2 + j

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Switch One Desktop Up'"
Control + Shift + Mod2 + k

# Zoom desktop with the mouse

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut view_zoom_in"
Mod4 + b:4

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut view_zoom_out"
Mod4 + b:5

# Move the current window to a desktop

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window One Desktop to the Left'"
Control + Mod2 + Mod4 + h

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window One Desktop to the Right'"
Control + Mod2 + Mod4 + l

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window One Desktop Down'"
Control + Mod2 + Mod4 + j

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window One Desktop Up'"
Control + Mod2 + Mod4 + k

# Minimize the current window

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Minimize'"
Control + Mod2 + Mod4 + m

# Tile windows

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Quick Tile Bottom Left'"
Control + Alt + KP_1

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Quick Tile Bottom Right'"
Control + Alt + KP_3

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Quick Tile Top Left'"
Control + Alt + KP_7

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Quick Tile Top Right'"
Control + Alt + KP_9

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Quick Tile Left'"
Control + Alt + KP_4

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Quick Tile Right'"
Control + Alt + KP_6

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Maximize'"
Control + Alt + KP_5

"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut 'Window Grow Horizontal'"
Control + Alt + KP_8

## end .xbindkeys
```

https://github.com/gerardbm/dotfiles/blob/master/.xbindkeysrc